# Probability game of black and white

Tags: probability

There are 10 doors and behind each one is a black or white image. We don't know how many black or white images there are in total.

The game is played by a number of players (less than 10) and each time one player guesses correctly they move to the next round. If noone guesses correctly the round is repeated. Once all doors are opened, they are closed again and shuffled (but a different number of white and black can occur).

In the final round, the two remaining players have to play until one of them reaches 5 correct guesses.
If what I wrote doesn't make sense you can take a look at the game here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzrFIUNufIc.

My question is, is there a mathematical way to approach this? Any way to make an educated and not completely random guess?

Comment: What a boring game to watch! Your probability of winning is the same no matter how you guess.

Comment: State as you have it, the game is completely and uniformly random, and any pick is as good as any other pick.However, assuming that players are eliminated when a round ends if any other players has moved to the next round, there is no guarantee that the last round will have exactly 2 remaining players.

Comment: @MarkFischler true. If it's 3 players, the first one to win moves to the final and the other two battle it out until one of them guesses correctly and the other does not.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I agree. I couldn't believe they chose this game in Survivor to give away a motorbike and a car... This is why I was asking. To see if someone can think of a way to "cheat"/make it more interesting to watch...